# Azure SQL Data Warehouse - parameterising an SSIS source query

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-synapse

I want to query my Azure DW as part of an SSIS data flow. I'm using an oleDb source to do this, however when I try to configure a parameter, I get the below error.

> Stored procedure sp_describe_undeclared_parameters does not exist or
>   is not supported. (Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0)

Is this possible? Do I need to dymanically generate the query instead?

Comment: what is the query used?

Comment: Just as an aside, SSIS is a fine tool, but what you're doing is pulling data out of your MPP system, optimised for billions of rows and many terabtyes of data, and pulling it into an SSIS pipeline, presumably on IaaS.  You might want to double-check that's the right thing to do and also consider Azure Data Factory.  It's a very tool different compared with SSIS but the [Copy Wizard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-copy-data-wizard-tutorial) has made things a bit easier, and if you want to move data from place to place in Azure you really need to get to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ADO.net provider to connect to Azure SQL Data Warehouse instead.

As per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-migrate-data), OLEDB is not fully supported, although you may find you can connect, the full set of features, including parameterising statements, is not supported:

[image: Successful package execution]

To parameterise the statement, use a combination of package-level parameters, SSIS variables and expressions.  In my example, I'm using a package-level parameter called `dimDate` which is an `Int32`.  I then use an SSIS variable called `@[User::sql]` to concatenate the stored proc I want to run and the parameter:

`"EXEC dbo.usp_getDimDate " + (DT_STR, 8, 1252) @[$Package::dimDate]`

[image: SSIS variable with expression]

Finally, make the SSIS variable the source fro the ADO.net `SqlCommand` using the Expressions section of the task:

[image: ADO.net SqlCommand with expression]